# What would I need to do to implement a grammar, parser and lexer in Antlr programatically without a grammar file?

Tags: java, antlr

From the examples I've seen online and what I've read so far, it seems that the typical approach to create a language using Antlr would require a `.g4` grammar file and a tool like the `maven-antlr-plugin` to generate Java sources based on this.

Is it possible to implement things from scratch without having a grammar file and having to use such a generator?

Without getting into too much boring details, we need to implement a language that will have quite a few dynamic parts defined at runtime and hard-coding them would not work for us. Hence my asking.

What would be required as minimum to implement this programmatically? An implementation of a lexer and a parser? What else?

Could somebody please provide an example of a minimalistic such implementation that doesn't require the generation of code?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be completely unpractical in general case. Antlr is a tool that generates parsers from grammar files... if you take away generating parsers (because that is "generating code") and using grammar files, then, really, you are just taking away the whole Antlr.

You could probably use some parts of the runtime library (perhaps ATNs? or some lower-level stuff, like CharacterStream), but on the whole you would pretty much need to write your own general parser / lexer from scratch.

Let me turn your question around: what do you want to gain from using Antlr?

Comment: Well, I would still like to use Antlr for parsing, listeners, ATN-s and so on. I'd like to use Antlr, but just not use it for generating the code, so that I can define certain things at runtime instead of at compile time.

Comment: The ATN is generated by ANTLR4 as the result of the grammar-to-parser process. No translation, no ATN.

Comment: @carlspring  Here's the problem: both parsing and calling listeners IS handled by the generated code. There is no generic parsing code in the antlr runtime (apart from some really low level stuff). As my answer states: the whole design of antlr is about having as little runtime as possible.

Comment: Is there any way to modify the lexer / parser after they have been generated from the grammar?

Comment: @carlspring: uhm... yes, they are text files after all... also, the sources of parsers are themselves created using templates (this is how antlr supports different languages), so you could probably provide a set of your own templates.

Comment: @carlspring: I strongly suspect that what you want is possible using antlr (there's plenty of extension points) - if you only ask a direct question detailing what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @fdreger: Would you be interested in having a chat on the topic? This is regarding an OSS project that we're working on. If yes, please feel free to join https://chat.carlspring.org/ and we can discuss things there.

Comment: @fdreger: For a clearer explanation and the related code, you could have a look at our issue (if you're interested) -- https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/issues/1310.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off implementing an [Earley parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser), which is essentially directly driven by a set of grammar rules.

Want a different language?  Revise the ruleset, hand it to the Earley parsing engine.

A more interesting question might be, "What kind of parsing machinery is effective/efficient for a grammar in which some of the rules are constant, and some are dynamic?"    I've been tracking parsing machinery  for a long time and haven't see this question posed let alone seen an answer for it.    I suspect you might get something useful if  you partially evaluated an Earley parser against your baseline paser with placeholders for the varying rules, but this is clearly a research project.

Comment: But isn't that pretty much the same as using ANTLR in the first place? You write grammar rules and let the parser generator generate a parser from those, no?

Comment: 1) ANTLR handles left recursion, deep lookaheads and ambiguities badly, Earley does fine. Grammar changes might make these hard to avoid  2) You have to be willing to call ANTLR (process fork) each time your grammar changes which seems like a lot of overhead. That might amortize if you use the revised grammar often enough.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Yeah, these were my conclusions exactly. In my case, part of the language might enabled on a modular basis, so that makes the generation of code based on a grammar file pretty useless and we can't generate and compile classes each time the application starts up.